# Is there a way to remove directive A by directive B before A even processed?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm looking for a way in AngulrJs to create parent directive and put inside it another directives like this:

```
<parent-directive>
    <child-directive>Hi 1</child-directive>
    <child-directive>Hi 2</child-directive>
</parent-directive>
```

What I want is for `parent-directive` to be able to remove one of the `child-directive` before this even processed.
I used `angular.element(child[1]).remove()` inside the `compile` function in `parent-directive` but it didn't work and the `child-directive` still processed before it's being removed.

**Update:**
[This is a good article](http://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives-part-2-transclusion/) to understand the order of executing

Comment: Your approach is correct. Remove the element in the parent's compile function. Are you sure you selected the right element?

Comment: Are you sure you did it in the compile function and not in the postLink?

Comment: I misread the post (regarding my now deleted answer). Thought you were trying to remove the outer (parent) directive first.

Comment: You could try var elems = element.find('child-directive'); elems[0].remove();

Comment: This works just fine: `element.children()[1].remove();`

Comment: @pixelbits & tasseKATT , yes I'm sure I picked the right element because it's being removed, and I'm doing this in the 'pre' stage of compile.

Comment: what do you mean by processed? What do you want to avoid? You want to avoid the directive controller from being called or what? Have you tried using a simple ng-if?

Comment: There is no 'pre' compile. What you're working with is 'pre' for the link phase which is not what you want.  Move your code outside of pre.

Comment: I make sure I did it correct or not by adding console.info('inked'); line to the Link function in the child-directive, if nothing came out to the console then it's being removed before processed.

Comment: @SimoneZandara how to use ng-if in this situation ? I need the parent directive to decide which child should be removed.

Comment: yea exactly, set a boolean flag for each nested directive, the flags are stored in the parent controller

Comment: @SimoneZandara I'm using:
angular.element(children[1]).attr('ng-if', false);
$compile(children[1])(scope);
But it although enters the link function of child directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove one of the children before its even processed by the AngularJS compiler, the place to do it is the `compile` function. The compile function of the parent is guaranteed to run before the child, so it gives you an opportunity to manipulate the DOM of the children ahead of the AngularJS compiler.

```
app.directive('parent-directive', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: function($element) {
            $element.children()[1].remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: no I don't think you have... This is not the same as putting inside the link function (which is inside the compile function). By the time that the link function is called, its too late.

Comment: you're very right, this is the correct answer, using this will not allow sub directives to work.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this does not answer your question directly, but it is able to remove a sub directive at compile time preventing its link method from being called. Using ng-if..

```
<parent-directive>
    <child-directive ng-if="subdivs.1">Hi 1</child-directive>
    <child-directive ng-if="subdivs.2">Hi 2</child-directive>
</parent-directive>
```

then in your parent-directive

```
demo.directive('parent', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.subdivs = {1: false, 2: true};
        }
    }})
```

This will only display 'Hi 2' and will only call the link method of 'Hi 2'. See jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4eg1ta6n/2/).